# Check the length of a textarea filled automatically in jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a MultiDatesPicker control where the user can select some dates. 
A textarea object filled automatically with dates, while the user selects some of them. Everything is working fine.
What I liked to do now is, to check the length of that textarea so when the length is > 60 to change its width to 200px and when is <=60 the width will be 90.
I have done the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['el']);
        $('#cPublDates').multiDatesPicker({
            altField: '#tbPublishDates'
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#tbPublishDates').change(function () {
                alert('changed');
                if ($(this).val().length > 60) {
                    $(this).width(200);
                } else {
                    $(this).width(90);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the objects are

```
        <div class="pulicationBox">
        <span id="cPublDates"></span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPublishDates" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Width="90px" />
    </div>
```

but didn't work because the change() event is not fired. The #tbPublishDates is the id of the textarea.
Any ideas or code correction would be welcome since I am newbie in jQuery.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is because it's the multidaypicker that adds values to the textarea, hence jquery change() won't trigger. I'd suggest you to use the multidatepicker event onSelect() to instead check the length of the textarea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['el']);
$('#cPublDates').multiDatesPicker({
    altField: '#tbPublishDates',
    onSelect: function(){
        alert('changed');
        if ($('#tbPublishDates').val().length > 60) {
            $('#tbPublishDates').width(200);
        } else {
            $('#tbPublishDates').width(90);
        }

   }
});
```

});

See the http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ documentation.

Comment: ok, I just tried and this makes the trick. Thanks a lot jtheman!

Answer (score 4):

Try, now with dynamic binding to the textbox...

Also make sure you have included the jQuery library version 1.7 or higher

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['el']);
    $('#cPublDates').multiDatesPicker({
        altField: '#tbPublishDates'
    });

        $('#tbPublishDates').on('change', function () {
            alert('changed');
            if ($(this).val().length > 60) {
                $(this).width(200);
            } else {
                $(this).width(90);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I didn't mention that the change event is not fired.

Comment: @Makis   added $(function() in the beginning if your script loads before the textbox... otherwise I'd like you to include also your HTML...

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't fire the change. I have edited my original post to include the whole jQuery code there is now with the html objects

Comment: @makis Well you can't have multiple $(function () { calls so just remove mine

Comment: not fired yet. The box fills/unfills with dates selections/unselection, but the alert inside the change() is not comes

Comment: jQuery version are ok:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I suggest you to use Firebug or something similar to doublecheck what is actually loaded in the DOM and see possible JS errors...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#tbPublishDates').change(function () {
        alert('changed');
        if ($(this).val().length > 60) {
            $(this).css('width','200');
        } else {
             $(this).css('width','90');
        }
    });
```